# "overflow:hidden" invalid in ie

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, overflow

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
html{ overflow:hidden;}
body{ overflow:hidden; height:100%; background-color:blue; margin:0px;}
div{ height:3000px; background-color:red; margin:30px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div>dasdasd</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the html code. When it running on a standard browser, the div tag keep showing in the window.
But it run in ie, when you select the words "dasdasd" and drag down, the body tag will scroll and the words "dasdasd" will hide unless you disable the select function.
Could someone give me other solution?

Like Spudley's answer,the DOCTYPE cause the problem,but when in the standard mode,the body tag still scroll, anyone can solve the problem?

Comment: It got nothing to do with `overflow` or CSS.

Comment: Also, please specify what version of IE are you using -- that may also make a difference.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're missing the `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration.

When IE sees HTML code without a DOCTYPE, it goes into quirks mode.

In quirks mode, the browser is effectively rendering the page to be backward compatible with IE5. It changes the way it renders the basic box layout, and removes support for a lot of standard CSS.

Add the following doctype to the top of your page (above the `<html>` tag), and you should see things come right:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: Now I can say "Aha !", just first time I know that, thank you :)

Comment: but the body tag also scroll in the standard mode, could you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
body {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
div {
    background-color: red;
    margin: 30px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Hope it works...Best Luck.